# Why is Maven (incorrectly?) deploying my SNAPSHOT to both the release and snapshot repositories?

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I'm currently experiencing a problem while trying to set up a project to deploy to an internal nexus repository.  Since I'm rather new to Maven in general, I expect that there is just something that I'm not really comprehending in how to set up distribution management.

The basic issue is that when I execute "mvn deploy" the artifact is being successfully deployed to the snapshot repository, but Maven is also attempting to deploy it to the release repository, which is failing ... as it should.  My understanding of my current configuration is that it should NOT be deploying it to the release repository as well.

I've included the various configuration elements below, but I'm wondering if I actually am supposed to be managing the  section with a profile so that snapshot builds only have  defined, and release builds have only  defined.

Any help/clarification on this would be incredibly appreciated.

I have the following in my POM for distribution management:

```
<distributionManagement>
<repository>
  <id>internal-releases</id>
  <name>Internal Releases</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
</repository>
<snapshotRepository>
  <id>internal-snapshots</id>
  <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
</snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Elsewhere in the POM I have the following set up to allow use of these repositories to obtain artifacts:

```
<repositories>
<repository>
  <id>internal-releases</id>
  <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
  <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>internal-snapshots</id>
  <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
  <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
</repository>
<!-- other repos, etc, etc -->
</repositories>
```

I have the correct settings in my settings.xml to provide credentials to be able to publish to this test nexus instance running on my computer, and it is in fact successfully deploying the snapshot.

The problem is that it also tries to deploy the snapshot to the release repository, which is configured to disallow snapshots.

The output from "mvn deploy" includes the following:

```
[INFO] [deploy:deploy {execution: default-deploy}]
[INFO] Retrieving previous build number from internal-snapshots
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/internal/service/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/service-1.0.0-20101104.170338-8.war
405K uploaded  (service-1.0.0-20101104.170338-8.war)
[INFO] Retrieving previous metadata from internal-snapshots
[INFO] Uploading repository metadata for: 'snapshot com.internal:service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO] Retrieving previous metadata from internal-snapshots
[INFO] Uploading repository metadata for: 'artifact com.internal:service'
[INFO] Uploading project information for service 1.0.0-20101104.170338-8
[INFO] [deploy:deploy-file {execution: default}]
[INFO] Retrieving previous build number from remote-repository
[INFO] repository metadata for: 'snapshot com.internal:service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' could not be found on repository: remote-repository, so will be created
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/internal/service/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/service-1.0.0-20101104.170338-1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error deploying artifact: Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/internal/service/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/service-1.0.0-20101104.170338-1.jar. Return code is: 400
```

The log from Nexus contains the following (as I would expect it to):

```
jvm 1    | 2010-11-04 13:03:39 INFO  [p-759477796-118] - o.s.n.p.m.m.M2Repos~          - Storing of item releases:/com/internal/service/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/service-1.0.0-20101104.170338-1.jar is forbidden by Maven Repository policy. Because releases is a RELEASE repository
jvm 1    | 2010-11-04 13:03:39 ERROR [p-759477796-118] - o.s.n.r.ContentPlex~          - Got exception during processing request "PUT http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/internal/service/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/service-1.0.0-20101104.170338-1.jar": Storing of item releases:/com/internal/service/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/service-1.0.0-20101104.170338-1.jar is forbidden by Maven Repository policy. Because releases is a RELEASE repository
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the best clue actually turned out to be right in front of my eyes in the log.  The only artifact I had thought was being produced by the POM I was working with was a .war, but you'll notice in the log that the artifact which Maven is attempting to deploy to the release is actually a .jar.

This was enough of a pointer (that someone on the Maven users mailing list pointed provided) to look for and eventually find that someone had included the following extra configuration for the deploy phase.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
<execution>
  <phase>deploy</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>deploy-file</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <generatePom>true</generatePom>
      <url>${project.distributionManagement.repository.url}</url>
      <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Notice that this is in fact directly referencing `${project.distributionManagement.repository.url}`.  Also, this configuration was somewhat misguided and should really have been accomplished via the `attachClasses` property of the war plugin.

Answer (score 9):

1. Define following property in your pom

   ```
   <deployFileUrl>${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.url}</deployFileUrl>
   ```
2. Change configuration  of maven-deploy-plugin as follows:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.5</version>
       <configuration>
           <skip>true</skip>
       </configuration>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <phase>deploy</phase>
               <configuration>
                   <packaging>jar</packaging>
                   <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                   <url>${deployFileUrl}</url>
                   <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                   <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                   <version>${project.version}</version>
                   <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
               </configuration>
               <goals>
                   <goal>deploy-file</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
   ```
3. Add following profile to set the deployFileUrl property with repository url

   ```
   <profiles>
       <profile>
           <id>release-mode</id>
           <properties>
               <deployFileUrl>${project.distributionManagement.repository.url}</deployFileUrl>
           </properties>
       </profile>
   </profiles>
   ```
4. Finally call this profile in maven-release-plugin

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.0-beta-9</version>
       <configuration>
           <releaseProfiles>release-mode</releaseProfiles>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because the artifact *version* does not have `-SNAPSHOT` suffix?

Comment: The artifact version is 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, so no.

Comment: This answer should be a comment, I think